# iOS - sharing code between view controllers

Tags: iphone, refactoring, uitabbarcontroller, viewcontroller

I have two view controllers - a `UIViewController` and a `UITableViewController`.

And they both require the same code for `barButtonItems` - a done button and a settings button. I think it's ugly having the same code for method selectors and in `viewDidLoad`, but I can't think of any other way to have the same `barButtonItems` for the two controllers.

The shared code looks like:

```
- (void)dismissViewController { [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; }
- (void)done:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender { [self dismissViewController]; }
- (void)settings:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender { [self performSegueWithIdentifier:SETTINGS_SEGUE sender:sender]; }

- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];

   if (self.navigationController.viewControllers.count == 1)
     self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Settings" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(settings:)];
   self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(done:)];
}
```

Architecturally, my code is like this:

```
UITabBarController -view controllers->
    UINavigationController -root view controller-> UIViewController
    UINavigationController -root view controller-> UITableViewController
```

So, is there a way to share code between the `UIViewController` and `UITableViewController`? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you really want, you could create a static method *initNavigationBar* where you pass in the `navigationItem`.

```
+ (void ) initNavigationBar: (UiNavigationItem *) navigationItem 
{
      navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
         initWithTitle:@"Settings" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
         target:selfaction:@selector(settings:)];

      navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 

}
```

But think twice if that makes sense.

Comment: thanks! never tried using `target: self` in a static method before, I'll try.

Comment: o, not self, tzhe reason is that you pass self , or self.navigationItem to that method as argument.